# Safari fixed position

Tags: html, css, safari

I have an application made with React.js. I have a navigation menu at the bottom of the page on mobile version, I want to highlight the main button so that it overflows the navigation bar, it works very well with google chrome but on safari, I don't see what comes out of the navbar.

I tried to add a `z-index` and change with a `position: absolute;` but nothing does

```css
#new-lunch-button-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Chrome
[image: Chrome version]

Safari
[image: Safari version]

Generated html code
[image: generated html code]

Comment: It works fine on firefox too !

Comment: could you add your html of the problem area? Pics are good but code is king

Comment: @zgood It's true I should have done it right away, it's done!

Comment: What are the styles on that image and the nav container? I can't tell if the button is being clipped by the navigation or covered by the image. When you scroll, what happens?

Comment: it is cut off by navigation, the bottom navbar is floating